# Why doesn't accelerating reference frames in QFT lead to horrible paradoxes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames

### Background

So I remember that in Special Relativity while one can define acceleration things can go horribly wrong has happened [historically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox) (I'm sure there many other paradoxes). The real reason of things going wrong is while in special relativity on can talk about acceleration in a limited sense it does not make sense globally.

### Question

How is it that in QFT (Special Relativity + Quantum Mechanics) we do not arrive at any sort of paradox like in the case of special relativity talking about QFT due to this?

P.S: I am aware this question is similar to: [Equivalence Principle holding in Special Relativity? (let alone QFT)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502408/equivalence-principle-hold-in-special-relativity-let-alone-qft?noredirect=1#comment1132570_502408) (However, I am of the opinion to know if it were a duplicate I'd need an answer for the previous one)

Comment: Acceleration works fine in special relativity, as long as you define acceleration correctly. For example, Rindler coordinates describe a uniformly-accelerating reference frame: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates

Comment: @probably_someone Lemme summarise your position: If the manifold has a Lorentz metric then in the case of dynamics a particle follow a geodesic: ${\displaystyle ds^{2}=-(\alpha x)^{2}dt^{2}+dx^{2}+dy^{2}+dz^{2}}$ ... Fair enough ... But this gives the illusion that one can use acceleration in a non-inertial frame as well?

Comment: Well, yes, metrics can be used in non-inertial frames. You just can't apply the same conclusions that are drawn in inertial frames if you're not in one. For example, in Rindler coordinates there's an event horizon (the Rindler horizon) a fixed distance behind you, beyond which you are unable to observe any events.

Comment: Yes, but to talk about "acceleration" in that context we're going outside special relativity ... I'm not sure in QFT if no one has ever tried to start from a non-inertial frame (or if they say "not allowed")

Comment: What makes you think this is "going outside special relativity"? We're talking about an accelerating object in a flat spacetime. And QFT in non-inertial frames has already been considered: for example, the Unruh effect predicts that an accelerating observer will observe that the QFT vacuum experienced by an inertial observer looks like a warm gas with a temperature proportional to the observer's acceleration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect

Comment: @probably_someone hmm ... Maybe I should just repharse the question as: in QFT does: "the laws of special relativity hold in an infinitesimal region around a freely-falling observer"? About the Unruh effect I was under the impression that it was the forefront of research

Comment: That's not just something that holds in QFT, that's a general statement from general relativity. In GR, if you take a small enough patch of spacetime, the spacetime curvature approaches zero (in other words, spacetime is everywhere "locally Minkowski").

Comment: And the Unruh effect has been in the literature since 1973, so not exactly the forefront of theoretical research. Efforts at actually detecting the Unruh effect are currently being discussed, but it's not like people are just thinking about this now - they've been thinking about QFT in non-inertial frames for over 50 years.

Comment: @probably_someone I'm very confused now ... "That's not just something that holds in QFT" .... So does it hold in Special Relativity too ?? I was under the impression QFT = SR + QM ??

Comment: Maybe you can tell us something we don't know here? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502408/equivalence-principle-holding-in-special-relativity-let-alone-qft?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I think what you might want to ask first is this: can non-relativistic accelerations result in nontrivial influences in QFT cross-sections? (nontrivial meaning, other than coordinate and momentum classical transformations of on-shell legs)

Comment: @lurscher that's quite an interesting question. I suspect you have an answer too? If so link please?

Comment: no I don't, that's why I'm suggesting you to make that question first

Comment: Do u know the answer? Maybe we can just head over to chat then?

Answer (score 3):

Let's go into the details of the definition of QFT in particle physics, more than quantum mechanics and special relativity combined.

> *[QFT treats particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory)* as excited states (also called quanta) of their underlying fields, which are—in a sense—more fundamental than the basic particles. Interactions between particles are described by interaction terms in the Lagrangian involving their corresponding fields. Each interaction can be visually represented by Feynman diagrams, which are formal computational tools, in the process of relativistic perturbation theory.

It is a mathematical tool for particle *interactions* , *and acceleration has no meaning within this framework*, because all interactions happen through virtual particles according to the appropriate interactions, strong , weak or electromagnetic. You cannot accelerate an electron in  QFT, you can write a Feynman diagram for its increase in energy with an interaction of a photon.

The basic fields are represented by plane wave solutions, Dirac for fermions, Klein-Gordon for bosons, quantized Maxwell for photons. Creation and annihilation operators operating on these fields give the interactions and Feynman diagrams the tools to calculate them.

Everything is Lorentz invariant.

*Please note that quantum field theory is a calculational tool that has been used for other frames than particle physics, where wavefunctions can be defined.*

So  accelerated observer frameworks  with respect to the interactions happening do not affect the calculations using QFT in particle physics, i.e. crossections, lifetimes etc.  The QFT  calculations are done in the center of  mass system of the particles, and results can be translated to other frames without having to involve QFT.

Accelerated observer frames will not affect the calculations for measureable interactions between elementary particles.

The effect of observer acceleration on the QFT vacuum is being studied in new theories , for [example here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00043),

> In this article,  we have presented the theory of accelerated quantum electrodynamics and used it to explore the radiation produced by uniform accelerated motion

but no contradictions with data measurements are found, or paradoxes.

Comment: I remember reading some Cambridge book where the person defined some acceleration 4 vector... Also can I get a reference for acceleration has no meaning within this framework? And is the unruh effect considered qft?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous it is about an accelerating observer, the acceleration is on the observer, qft is used but it is not specific to QFT for particles which is a tool for particle interactions, imo.

Comment: In relativity we have this beautiful thing that even if a particle is accelerating then you can ask how would the particle "see" you ... I can see that running into problems in QM where the particle is in superposition ... Maybe there is a need for a distinction as you say ...

Comment: I apologise I have changed the title to make it clearer what I'm going on about ... May you update your answer in light of that?

Comment: any examples of situation where "where wavefunctions can('t) be defined."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix  . The wavefunction becomes irrelevant to quantum mathematics when the densty matrix becomes diagonal. This happens for large dimensions, when h can be set equal to zero, within the accuracies of observation. This is the classical frame

Comment: so density matrix can't be used to describe an accelerating frame... Also about h to $0$. I've always been uncomfortable setting a dimensional quantity to $0$

Comment: You should not be. It is what distinguishes the classical regime , from the quantum. If h is significant to the measurements , it is the quantum regime.

Comment: "The quasi-classical limit of quantum mechanics refers, roughly speaking, to the limit ℏ → $0$. Of course, ℏ is a dimensionful constant, but in practice one studies the semi-classical regime of a given quantum theory by forming a dimensionless combination of ℏ and other parameters; this combination then re-enters the theory as if it were a dimensionless version of ℏ that can indeed be varied."

Taken from:https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-70626-7_182 
Also you lemme know for certain that density matrices can't be used for accelerating frames?

Comment: In the quantum regime, density matrix is just a way to deal mathematically with the complexity of many particles, eqivalent to the other mathematical formulations.. If somebody can use it to explore the regime of accelerating observers , another theory like the one I linked, there should be no problem. It is when it becomes diagonal that one cannot be talking of quantum mechanics. As for dimensionful numbers, as an experimentalist everything I measure has a dimension, which measurement can be used to generate dimensionless numbers.

Comment: I’m surprised that no one mentioned Unruh radiation so far. QFT in the Rindler frame is far from being trivial.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov  but they have, the last link I give mathematically models  Unruh also